# How do modern web applications implement caching and data persistence with large amounts of rapidly changing data?

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, caching, redis

For example, consider something like Facebook or Twitter. All the user tweets / posts are retained indefinitely (so they must ultimately be stored within a static database). At the same time, they can rapidly change (e.g. with replies, likes, etc), so some sort of caching layer is necessary (e.g. you obviously can't be writing directly to the database every time a user "likes" a post).

In a case like this, how are the database / caching layers designed and implemented? How are they tied together?

For example, is it typical to begin by implementing the database in its entirety, and then add the caching layer afterword?

What about the other way around? In other words, begin by implementing the majority of functionality into the cache layer, and then write another layer which periodically flushes the cache to the database (at some point when its activity has gone down)? In this scenario, for current / rapidly changing data, the entire application would essentially be stored in cache.

Or perhaps implement some sort of cache-ranking algorithm based on access / update frequency?

How then should it be handled when a user accesses less frequent data (which isn't currently in cache)? Simply bypass cache completely / query the database directly, or should all data be cached before it's sent to users?

In cases like this, does it make sense to design the database schema with the caching layer in mind, or should it be designed independently?

I'm not necessarily asking for direct answers to all these questions, but they're just to give an idea of where I'm coming from.

I've found quite a bit of information / books on implementing the database, and implementing the caching layer independent of one another, but not a whole lot of information on using them in conjunction / tying them together.

Any information, suggestions, general patters, articles, books, would be much appreciated. It's just difficult to find some direction here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best solution, but I worked on a personal project using Openresty where I used their [shared memory zones](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#lua_shared_dict) to cache, to avoid the overhead of connecting to something like Redis, then used Redis as the backend DB.

When a user loads a resource, it checks the shared dict, if it misses then it loads it from Redis and writes it to the cache on the way back.

If a resource is created or updated, it's written to the cache, and also queued to a shared dict queue.

A background worker ticks away waiting for new items in the queue, writing them to Redis and then sending an event to other servers to either invalidate the resource in their cache if they have it, or even pre-cache it if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I wasn't familiar with Openresty. Using Redis as a standalone DB is an interesting idea. I just came across an article from 2014 that said Twitter allocates 105TB of RAM for Redis in each datacenter (for their timeline service), so that seems to be a more viable option these days (assuming you have the funds to run your database in memory).

Comment: Redis also supports sharing the data across multiple machines using cluster, so you don't need one big machine with hundreds of gigs of RAM.